# Jinja2 - Loop over list to build a table

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am quite new to Flask and I am having a hard time to understand why I am only getting a list of  elements in my browser (single column), I would like to get 3 different columns and my data is correct:

[image]

```
   <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Mail</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>

        {% for n in customers %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{n['First Name']}} </td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{n['Last Name']}}</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ n['Phone']}}</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr>
           <td> <a href="/delete/{{ n['Phone'] }}">Supprimer</a> <td></td>
        </tr>                      
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Comment: <tr> stands for table row. So after the first name, you go to a new row. Replace that with what you do for the headers, and you will get a row per person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are really looking for is something like this:

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Mail</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for n in customers %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{n['First Name']}} </td> 
                    <td>{{n['Last Name']}}</td> 
                    <td>{{ n['Phone']}}</td> 
                    <td> <a href="/delete/{{ n['Phone'] }}">Supprimer</a> <td></td>
                </tr>                      
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
</table>
```

`tr` Stands for Table Row. Check out [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) to learn a bit more about tables